# query on connect by clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables

```
table 1 

vic_id | part 1 
----------------
11       ch
12       bo
13       dd
14       gm
15       mh
16       sh
17       vai
18       bal
19       gur
20       ma
21       ar
22       st
23       in
24       va
25       vi
```

---

```
table 2

 parent || child
 ---------------
  11        12
  12        13
  11        14
  14        15
  11        17
  17        15
```

---

I want the structure which ends with

```
11-14-15(ch-gm-mh) 
11-17-15(ch-vai-mh)
```

I want the query to give count as 2

i tried working with

`connect by parent=child`
and `start with parent`  but don't get the expected result.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hierarchical queries using `connect by` allows you join two levels together e.g. child-ancestor. In your case you seem to want to recursively concatenate values starting from the root and descending in the tree.

To achieve the end result you look into nested subqueries using `WITH` for example (NON-TESTED QUERY)

```
WITH RECURSIVE
    roots AS ( 
       SELECT parent, part1 
       FROM table2 
       JOIN table1 on parent = vic_id
       WHERE parent NOT IN (SELECT child FROM table2)),
    res AS (
       SELECT parent cur, part1 cur_part, parent ids, part1 parts
       FROM roots 
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 
             child cur, 
             part1 cur_part,
             ids||'-'||child,
             parts||'-'||part1
       FROM res
       JOIN table2 on cur = parent
       JOIN table2 on child = vic_id
    )
SELECT ids, parts
FROM res
WHERE ids like '11%';
```